# How to set constraints on a Python Input string

Tags: python

I want the user to be able to input their name, and to set constraints so that only things like letters, periods, and spaces are allowed and the rest (numbers, etc.) throws an error.

I tried using the isalpha() function with an if/else statement inside a while loop to reprompt the user if numbers are included in the input.

However isalpha() only accepts letters, and nothing else. For example, user inputs with spaces or periods such as "Bob Smith", "Dr. Smith", or "Anne-Marie" would throw an error.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you have two more conditions to check for `.` and `-` in the string?

Comment: Try to check `re.match`

Comment: There are many options. Using regular expressions would be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with regular expressions.
Just check if input string containing only allowed chars.

```
import re

def is_valid_name(str):
    pattern = "^[a-zA-Z\ \.\-]+$"
    return bool(re.search(pattern,str))

print is_valid_name("Bob Smith")
print is_valid_name("Dr. Smith")
print is_valid_name("Anne-Marie")
print is_valid_name("Anne!Marie")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
def nameChecker(inputName):
    # Remove valid characters from the string
    validChars = [" ",".","-"]
    for char in validChars:
        inputName = inputName.replace(char,"")

    # Check if the remaining string is valid
    return inputName.isalpha()
```

I believe that is what you are looking for, please let me know if this works for you!